# Using Sendgrid Handlebars to call JSON Data

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm using the following JSON to create a SendGrid template:

```
    { "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "to@email.com" } ], "custom_args": { "refnum": "222111", "datetime": "Monday, 4:30" } } ], "from": { "name": "From Person", "email": "marketing@email.com" }, "reply_to": { "name": "reply-to-name", "email": "reply-to@email.com" }, "template_id": "template-id888939333", "tracking_settings": { "click_tracking": { "enable": true, "enable_text": true }, "open_tracking": { "enable": true }, "ganalytics": { "enable": true, "utm_source": "autoeml", "utm_medium": "email", "utm_content": "222111", "utm_campaign": "email" } } }
```

The template sends fine - I'm unable to get the handlebars to show in the email template, I've tried all of the following:

```
{{personalizations.custom_args.refnum}}
{{custom_args.refnum}}
{{refnum}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made two updates to get this to work.

Instead of using the `addCustomArg` library in PHP, I updated to use the `addDynamicTemplateDatas` and also updated the handlebars to have a space before and after the variable name: `{{ refnum }}`.

It still didn't come through in the template editor, but it is verified to be in the sent email.